# Hola, soy nuevo en esto de MySQL al intentar crear una tabla no me permite crearla

Tags: mysql-workbench

[image: Esto es lo que me aparece]

Este es el código que la propia aplicación crea por si sola

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios`.`usuarios` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usuario` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `correo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_session` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT 0000-00-00 00:00:00,
  `id_tipo` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

no creo que la aplicación misma cree un código que no puede ejecutar algo yo he de tener mal configurado, la cuestión es que no me crea la tabla y es por lo anteriormente mencionado

Answer (score 1):

probablemente tengas un error en el valor que le has dado a la columna `last_session`, ya que, no está en el formato correcto.

En lugar de utilizar `DEFAULT 0000-00-00 00:00:00`, debes encerrar el valor predeterminado entre comillas simples, como `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`. De esta manera, MySQL interpretará correctamente el valor como una cadena de texto.

Intenta haciéndolo de la siguiente forma:

```
   CREATE TABLE `usuarios`.`usuarios` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usuario` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `correo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_session` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `id_tipo` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```